# How recent are 'recent tags'?

Tags: support, recent-tags

I wonder, the block on the right that says 'recent tags' with tags and counter next to them, how recent?

I mean the tag/counter data, I can see it does not reflect the absolute count of tags on this site, so then what do these counts reflect? Number of tags in the last 24 hours, last month?

Please explain.

thanks

Comment: Can't believe nobody has an answer to this!